# How to make depth of nii images equal?

Tags: python, image-processing, medical

I am having some `nii` images and each having same height and width but different depth. So I need to make the depth of each image equal, how can I do that? Also I didn't find any Python code, which can help me.

Comment: Do you want a simple way to just increase the depth of each images to a fixed value or to you need to shrink images as well ?

Comment: @Pierre-NicolasPiquin just need to make depth equal.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have defined the depth you want for all volumes, let it be D, you can instantiate an image (called *volume* when D > 1) of dimensions W x H x D, for every volume you have.

Then you can fill every such volume, pixel by pixel, by mapping the pixel position onto the original volume and retrieving the value of the pixel by interpolating the values in neighboring pixels.

For example, a pixel (i_x, i_y, i_z) in the new volume will be mapped in a point (i_x, i_y, i_z') of the old volume. One of the simplest interpolation methods is the linear interpolation: the value of (i_x, i_y, i_z) is a weighted average of the values (i_x, i_y, floor(i_z')) and (i_x, i_y, floor(i_z') + 1).

Comment: Can you also provide me link to some python code or library, it will be great help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to add zeros to to your data to get the same depth, here is a way to do it :

```
import numpy as np

width = 2
height = 2
depth1 = 3
depth_max = 5

t = np.zeros(shape=(height, width, depth1))

print(t.shape)  # (2, 2, 3)

t_with_new_depth = np.block([t, np.zeros(shape=(height, width, depth_max - depth1))])

print(t_with_new_depth.shape)  # (2, 2, 5) with 0 on the newly added depth channels
```